# Prove $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$ ...

Tags: real-analysis

such that $\forall x \in Dom(f)$,$0 <|x-c|\le \delta$ implies $|f(x)-L| \le \epsilon$

I am really unsure about how to prove this. I tried to follow a similar approach as with proving continuity at c, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: What is your definition of $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x) = L$?  Usually what you wrote is taken as the definition so that there would be nothing to prove.

Comment: @Addem Not quite. Here there are $\leq$ and not $<$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $f$ is continuous then you have the same statement except with $<$ instead of $\leq$. Just consider what happens when you let $\delta'=\frac{\delta}{2}$ and/or $\epsilon'=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$